# Issue with saml_idp Rails gem, undefined method `authn_request?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, saml-2.0

So I'm using [this gem](https://github.com/sportngin/saml_idp) for SAML. Serivce provider is already set and connected in the initializer, and I have this in my controller.

```
class SamlIdpController < SamlIdp::IdpController

 skip_before_filter :validate_saml_request, only: [:new, :create]

 def idp_authenticate(email, password)
  user = User.find_by_email(email)
  user && user.valid_password?(password) ? user : nil
 end

 private :idp_authenticate

 def idp_make_saml_response(found_user)
  encode_response found_user
 end

 private :idp_make_saml_response

end
```

When I try to login, I get this error:

```
F, [2016-11-03T14:58:50.416637 #15024] FATAL -- : 
NoMethodError (undefined method `authn_request?' for nil:NilClass):
app/controllers/saml_idp_controller.rb:13:in `idp_make_saml_response'
```

The official wiki of the gem is pretty straight forward. I also tried passing 'user' instead of 'found_user' but getting the same error. What does that method expects? I'm I missing something here? Any help is welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: Sure about this? There isn't `authn_request` in my code, unless is something wrong with the gem.

Comment: Just checked the gem, the spelling is corrent. It's `authn_request`